# Function with infinite arguments?

Tags: functions

I am learning about functions of functions, and I wonder if the following declarations are well-defined functions?

Let $\{f_m\}$ be a sequence of functions such that $f_m\in \Bbb R^{(\Bbb R^m)}$.
\begin{align}
&y\colon \{1,2\} \times \Bbb R^{(\Bbb R^2)}\times \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R \\
&y(m, f, x_1,x_2) = 
\begin{cases}
f_1(x_1) & \text{if m = 1} \\
f_2(x_1,x_2) & \text{if m = 2} \\
\end{cases}
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
&y\colon \Bbb N \times \Bbb R^{(\Bbb R^{\aleph_0})}\times \Bbb R^{\aleph_0} \to \Bbb R \\
&y(m, f, x_1,x_2,\dots) = 
\begin{cases}
f_1(x_1) & \text{if m = 1} \\
f_2(x_1,x_2) & \text{if m = 2} \\
\vdots
\end{cases}
\end{align}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the functions you describe make sense, their domains (as it stands) do not. You write that $\{f_m\}$ is a sequence of functions in $\mathbb R^{\mathbb R^m}$; I take it that you write $f$ for the whole collection $\{f_m\}$. This means that $f$ must live in a set that's something like
$$
\{f : \mathbb N \to \bigcup_{m \in \mathbb N} \mathbb R^{\mathbb R^m} \mid f(m) \in \mathbb R^{\mathbb R^m}\},
$$
and not just in $\mathbb R^{\mathbb R^2}$. Thus you need to fix the definition of the domain of your first $y$.

The second function suffers from essentially the same problem: if we go by the domain, then $f$ is a function which takes infinitely many arguments from $\mathbb R$ and produces an element of $\mathbb R$. It doesn't make sense for $f$ to get applied to fewer elements. Again, you probably mean that the function $f$ should be drawn from the same set I defined above. Then your definition makes sense.